# How to link projects to portfolio website?

Tags: project, portfolio

I have finished creating my web developer portfolio and hosted it on github. However I am stuck with further 2 tasks below:

1. How to link my other projects to my portfolio website? If I upload those project files on github as well, then how do I make them available on portfolio so that when recruiter clicks on them, it takes them to the homepage of that project? (e.g., when we click on Live Demo button and we are directed to that project website)
2. How to make resume available in downloadable pdf format so that recruiter can download resume from portfolio website?

Please note, I do not want to spend on hosting or purchasing of any server portion at this stage. So how do I make my resume available to download?

Thank you.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to have links that will show your projects and not your code? If so, you could always use github pages for static hosting.

`https://github.com/YourUsername/YourRepo/settings` and then activate `GitHub Pages`

Comment: I want to do both: Show live demo and code. I see that all portfolios have 2 option for projects: Live Demo and See Code. When clicked on Live Demo, user is directed to project website and when clicked on 'See Code' option, user is taken to github repository. For See code option part I believe that we just have to link github repository URL from the address bar to the <a> tag in portfolio webpage. But how to link project website.

Comment: As you mentioned about using static hosting, does that mean I have to host project on github just like I hosted portfolio files and then how do I link that hosted project to portfolio. And then, what exactly do you mean by 'activate github pages'?

Answer (score 1):

Use the GitHub API for fetching the list of repositories and display it however you want.

```
GET/users/:username/repos

https://api.github.com/users/:username/repos
```

Check the API reference for [listing user repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories).

For the live demo link, you can make your link yourself with a bit of Js, as `'<username>.github.io/' + '<repository_name>/'`, or if you have enabled a custom domain then it will differ a bit.

---

Upload your resume file to a folder in your repo & link to it directly as you normally would for any file.